# Correct way to trigger file download?

Tags: javascript, html, download

In public/templates/calendar.html I have

```
<a href="" id="secret_download_button" style="display:none" download="">
```

In the same file I have a button (download qr), i make an ajax call from javascript, the qr gets created in /public/uploads/thumbs/qrcodes/'filename'
the ajax calls is finished and the following function is called which is in

public/javascript/some.js

```
function (data) {
        $('#secret_download_button').attr('href',data.content);
        $('#secret_download_button').attr('download','somename');
        $('#secret_download_button').click();
    });
```

data.content = public/upload/thumbs/qrcodes/someqr.png (example)

I need to use relative paths, not absolute paths. What am I doing wrong ? I am guessing that I am setting the href path wrong.
Also from what I read online this solution is not supported by IE. Is there another, simpler, more elegant way of doing this ( I need to be able to specify the name of the file which will be downloaded )

### Edit

Solved it server-side in the end. thanks. For anyone else having the same problem I used this:

```
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($activity_name . '.png').'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($root . $path . $file_name));
            readfile($root . $path . $file_name);
            exit;
```

Comment: What is your server-side language? If it's c#, you can make a GET request and return a `FileResult` to download the picture or file.

Comment: Why`'Pragma: public` ? It should be `Pragma: no-cache` if you are intending to use it like same way has `Cache-Control`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right, the download attribute is not supported by IE <s>nor Edge</s> (supported in Edge 13+) : http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

To have a cross-browser solution, you will have to open the url in the current window :

```
function (data) {
    window.location.href = data.content;
});
```

or a new window :

```
function (data) {
    window.open(data.content);
});
```

Two limitations:

- you can't set the filename client-side, you have to set it server side
- the browser will not download the file if it can read it (like images, pdf...), you will have to use the "save as"

Comment: Server can add header "Content-Disposition:attachment" and it will be always downloaded.